# has_many / belongs_to associations in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, has-many

I've read the guide on associations but I feel like I'm still not completely comprehending so I want to ask a couple of questions just to be sure.  Let's say I am making an app that will, among other things, list large cities all over the world.  I would plan on having a view that starts at continent level and can be filtered down.  So I would start with a Continent model.  And then a Country model.  Now, within the Continent model I would define an association as has_many :countries.  And in the Country model I would use belongs_to :continents.  That much I grasp.  So my next model would be a model for states / province.  Let's just call it Province since that is more common throughout the world.  So now I have my Province model, and I would use belongs_to :country.  And likewise Countries would have has_many :provinces.  My first question is, how do I describe the association between Province and Continent?  Has_many through describes associations where both models have many.  A Province only has one Continent.  Has_one through describes a relationship between objects that have a one to one relationship via a third object.  Again, this isn't the case because a Continent will have many Provinces.  So that is my primary question.. how to describe relationships that exist in a one to many through context.  My second question would be just asking for tips on writing the migrations for this in a situation where I add another layer, say County, later on.  But the main problem is just understand how to express the relationships I described.  Or if they even need to be expressed.

ETA:  If I were to use the has_many_through association, do I necessarily need to create a join table ( continent_province ), or can I simply use the countries table ie has_many :provinces -> through :countries?

Comment: A lot depends upon how you want to use the data. You don't need to define a direct link between Continent and Province unless you need that direct connection a lot. In that case, yes, you could do a `has_many_through`. It will associate many provinces with each Continent.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'm worried about the has_many_through association for two reasons.  First, it is defined as being between many to many, not many to one.  Secondly, if I were to use has_many_through, would I need to create a join table and use the join table as the "through" table?  It would seem to make so much more sense to use "Countries" as the "through" table, but that's not really the purpose of the Countries table.  Or am I just over-thinking this?  That's been known to happen.

Comment: Have you read through http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html?

Comment: Which continent are you going to place the country of Turkey in, and the city of Istanbul? I think the Turks have broken your data model.

Comment: @DavidAldridge:  The cities / provinces / countries / continents thing was hypothetical.  That's what I meant by "Let's say..."

Comment: @mrbatch:  I have read through the guide, several times.  Before and since posting my question.  I'm beginning to think tham my issue may have more to do with database design that associations.  I have a few pieces that I simply cannot make work regardless of the association, but I wouldn't have much problem writing simple queries for them in SQL.  I guess this tells me that I need to re-think my design, even though I could make it work in a different platform, so that it is more straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

Don't get too wound up around a couple of small examples in some doc somewhere. The relationship support is wonderfully flexible. In the end, just give it a try -- I have a Tester application that has all sorts of proof of concepts in it -- that's its purpose.

```
class Project
  # one-to-many 
  has_many :scenarios
  # linking through scenarios
  has_many :unittests, :through => :scenarios
  # polymorphic relationship, everything can be relation to one or more appls
  has_many :appllinks, :as => :applinkable, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :appls, :through => :appllinks, :order => 'name'
  blah blah blah
end

class Scenario
  # many-to-one 
  belongs_to :project
  # many-to-many
  has_many :scenariotests 
  has_many :unittests, :through => :scenariotests
  # polymorphic relationship, everything can be relation to one or more appls
  has_many :appllinks, :as => :applinkable, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :appls, :through => :appllinks, :order => 'name'
  blah blah blah
end

class Unittest
  # many-to-many
  has_many :scenariotests
  has_many :scenarios, :through => :scenariotests
  # polymorphic relationship, everything can be relation to one or more appls
  has_many :appllinks, :as => :applinkable, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :appls, :through => :appllinks, :order => 'name'
  blah blah blah
end
```